# Is this an error of MSDN? About pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, windows, arrays, winapi, pointers

At [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545793(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ,

```
typedef struct _FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION {
  ULONG  NextEntryOffset;
  UCHAR  Flags;
  UCHAR  EaNameLength;
  USHORT EaValueLength;
  CHAR   EaName[1];
} FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION, *PFILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION;
```

MSDN says at last line:

"The value(s) associated with each entry follows the EaName array. That is, an EA's values are located at **EaName + (EaNameLength + 1)**."

I think that's wrong, and the correct one should be

"The value(s) associated with each entry follows the EaName array. That is, an EA's values are located at **EaName + EaNameLength**."

Who is correct?

PS:

At the sam page, MSDN says: "EaNameLength: The length in bytes of the EaName array. This value **does not include a null-terminator to EaName**."

Besides, MSDN **doesn't say** EaName must be terminated with a null character byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232069%28v=prot.20%29.aspx):

> `EaName` (variable) - An array of 8-bit ASCII characters that contains the extended attribute name **followed by a single terminating null character byte**.
>
> `EaNameLength` (1 byte): An 8-bit unsigned integer that contains the length, in bytes, of the extended attribute name in the `EaName` field. **This value MUST NOT include the terminating null character to `EaName`.**

The `+1` accounts for the null terminator.

Comment: At the sam page, MSDN says: "EaNameLength: The length in bytes of the EaName array. This value does not include a null-terminator to EaName."

Comment: @xmllmx "This value" refers to `EaNameLength`, not `EaName`.

Comment: But MSDN doesn't say EaName must be terminated with a null character byte. I think I cannot make such a supposition if the documentation doesn't say so.

Comment: @xmllmx: Please see the direct quotes from the MSDN that I include in my answer.